# How could this happen? Records declared without checked out user

Tags: check-out, records-management

I have a bunch of records that exist on my sharepoint site that have somehow become records without being checked out to a user....

Any idea how that could be possible? I was under the impression that once something is declared a record that it is ultimately checked out by the "System Account"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though this issue was caused by our bulk uploader product that we had purchased. I was able to use the method [here](http://standardanomaly.com/index.php/blog/31-bypass-locks-on-a-sharepoint-document) to unlock the records.